# MPAndroidChart Pie is drawing incorrect chart when one value is very big

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using mpandroidchart library to draw Bar chart for my **ANDROID** app. I deleted all background lines except horizontal lines. How to delete them?

[image]

Comment: Bad.... Bad image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
xAxis.disableGridDashedLine();

YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false); //If you do not want Axis Line.
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false); //If you do not want Grid Line.

YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
rightAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false); //If you do not want Axis Line.
rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false); //If you do not want Grid Line.
```

**Hope this answer will help you.**

Answer (score 1):

To remove horizontal lines, use

```
YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

and

```
YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

To remove vertical lines, use

```
XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxix.setDrawGridLines(false);
```